# Branch to link blocked on facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, branch.io

I am stuck with a situation that I have implemented Branch.io iOS SDK not and generating a link for sharing. But I am facing an issue that if the app wants to share that link on Facebook, in that case, it is giving an error that **"There was a problem sharing your link"**.

Apart from direct sharing from my app if I try the with direct facebook app then facebook blocks my post by giving reason that **this link is blocked due to security reasons.**

Please help me out.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand. You are saying that your link you want to share gets blocked by Facebook and even if you wrap it in a branch.io link it still is blocked?

Comment: is your link contents Advertising  ?

Comment: @WizKid : Link which i want to share on facebook is deep linked bind by Branch.io , this is giving error by sharing my app. But if i copy -paste that link on direct facebook(Default App) in that case facebook bloacked this.

Comment: @MAhipal Singh: Link in bind with Branch io (Deep link), which has my applications path or url.

Comment: Hello all, Aaron from [Branch](https://branch.io/) here. We are aware of this situation where not all our links are shareable to Facebook. We will resolve this ASAP.

Comment: @aaron Still not resolved.

Comment: @aaron this issue is still not resolved. Our link also have the same issue: https://twlive.app.link/yp14qQSQfX

Comment: @aaron any news ? My links also get blocked by Facebook

Comment: Hello! I am facing the same problem now. But if I create a new deeplink URL then it works. Is facebook taking my old branch link as spam?

Comment: This happens due to you are using the testing link. When you will use live links it will work fine.